# Searching with Laravel or_where()

Tags: php, laravel

My goal is to search for a first and last name using Laravel. As the code is written, it searches for a First Name **or** Last Name, what I would like to do is get it to search for both First Name **and** Last Name. How would I accomplish this?

**PHP - Search Statement**

```
public function search($search_input) {
   $response = DB::table(self::$table)
          ->select(array(
            'ID',
            'User_ID',
            'Signup_Date',
            'First_Name',
            'Last_Name',
             DB::raw('CONCAT(First_Name," ",Last_Name) AS Name')
        ))
        ->where('First_Name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
        ->or_where('Last_Name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
        ->where_not_null('User_ID')
        ->order_by('Signup_Date', 'desc')
        ->get();
   return $response;
}
```

*EDIT:* I forgot to include we are using Laravel 3. https://laravel3.veliovgroup.com/docs/database/fluent

Comment: Change `or_where` to `where`. It's as simple as that.

Comment: or where is a legitimate query, but not as OP wrote it, it's `orWhere`, camelCase, not snake_case. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#parameter-grouping).

Comment: why not whereColumn ?

Comment: Sorry @Andrew you just reminded me I forgot to include what version we were using, Laravel 3. I put an edit in the post.

Comment: Use `where` instead of `or_where`?

Comment: I tried using `where` instead of `or_where`. That still only returns Firstname or Lastname, I think the problem is the space between the two names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, your query condition is

```
(First_Name LIKE "%xx%" OR Last_name LIKE "%xx%") AND User_id IS NOT NULL
```

You should modify your query as below to use [nested where clauses](https://laravel3.veliovgroup.com/docs/database/fluent#nested-where):

```
public function search($search_input) {
   $response = DB::table(self::$table)
          ->select(array(
            'ID',
            'User_ID',
            'Signup_Date',
            'First_Name',
            'Last_Name',
             DB::raw('CONCAT(First_Name," ",Last_Name) AS Name')
        ))
        ->where(function($query) use ($search_input) {
             $query->where('First_Name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
             ->or_where('Last_Name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%');
        }
        ->where_not_null('User_ID')
        ->order_by('Signup_Date', 'desc')
        ->get();
   return $response;
}
```

Comment: `snake_case` methods are being used because it is Laravel 3.

Comment: Thank @GeorgeHanson, I didn't think about that version :D

Comment: Actually had a question @HieuLe. Is the $query variable a Larvel global variable? I would like to understand what that variable is in this situation.

Comment: Hi @GiBiT09, the `$query` variable is not global. It is a nested query instance that is created by Laravel and will be passed to your closure (the whole parameter of the `where` method) when you call `where` method with a function as its argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you have it search both first name and last name, then I doubt it would return results. Because it would imply the search query would have to match a record where the input is like the first name and like the last name. I think what you are actually after is more of a compound search. As you have the selects in your query, you might be able to do the following instead.

```
public function search($search_input) {
  $response = DB::table(self::$table)
      ->select(array(
        'ID',
        'User_ID',
        'Signup_Date',
        'First_Name',
        'Last_Name',
         DB::raw('CONCAT(First_Name," ",Last_Name) AS Name')
    ))
    ->where('Name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
    ->where_not_null('User_ID')
    ->order_by('Signup_Date', 'desc')
    ->get();
   return $response;
}
```

This should work because `Name` is being set by the `CONCAT` function.

Comment: That was the issue, Name wasn't working. That would of made too much sense and been way to easy. I had to do the version that I accepted best answer for. A Nested Where Clause. Thanks for the input and answer though.